# Parsing the value of prefab(UILabel) in other script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to know how can I access the value of prefab. For example, I created a ngui progress bar on the scene and the percentage is showed allowing the position of progress bar. The progress bar is prefab and I want to access the value of percentage in other script using 'GetComponent'.

This is the script of uiroot Strat() method :

```
protected virtual void Start ()
{
    // Here - > Showing Null Exception

    UILabel uiLabel = GetComponent<UILabel> ();
    Debug.Log (uiLabel.text);
    // end

    UIOrthoCamera oc = GetComponentInChildren<UIOrthoCamera>();

    if (oc != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("UIRoot should not be active at the same time as UIOrthoCamera. Disabling UIOrthoCamera.", oc);
        Camera cam = oc.gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>();
        oc.enabled = false;
        if (cam != null) cam.orthographicSize = 1f;
    }
    else Update();
}
```

This is the script of UILabel (prefab) :

```
public void SetCurrentPercent ()
{
    if (UIProgressBar.current != null)
        text = Mathf.RoundToInt(UIProgressBar.current.value * 100f) + "%";
    // I want to access this text!!!
    Debug.Log (text);
}
```

### How can I access the 'text' in somewhere?

The errors are occurred in both of cases.

## 1.

```
Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UIRoot.cs(151,64): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected
Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UIRoot.cs(151,52): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(UnityEngine.Object)' has some invalid arguments
Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UIRoot.cs(151,52): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `UnityEngine.Object'
```

## 2.

```
Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UIRoot.cs(153,35): error CS0176: Static member `UILabel.value' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You could instantiate the prefab to read the value from the instance.</strike>

Your script only needs to hold a reference to your prefab.

```
public UILabel prefab; // assign this in the inspector

protected virtual void Start()
{
    Debug.Log(prefab.text);

    ...
}
```

To assign the prefab (so that it's not null), click on your UIRoot script in your scene, and drag the prefab from the "Project" tab to the prefab slot on the "Inspector" tab.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you ... I edited my question. Could you check it again?

Comment: @홍의숙 I see... I have changed my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late feedback.

I got the error below.
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to`UnityEngine.GameObject'

and I realized that i have to call the child of parent.
The Prefab which is an Object had child that i wanted to get component.
In conclusion, I figured out easily. It was very simple problem.

Here is the piece of script below.

```
<script>
UILabel UILabel = GameObject.Find ("third").GetComponentInChildren<UILabel> ();
print (UILabel.text);
```